# Flexbox properties in Android browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div with `display:flex;` and inside there is a text that I need to align horizontally and vertically.

This is working on Chrome, Mozilla and IE but I need that works on Android browser too. Is there some fix for that?

Container div

```
.s_container{
    display:-webkit-flex; 
    display:-webkit-box; 
    display:-moz-flex;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
}
```

Text div

```
.ssm_option{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 50px;
    display: flex;  
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: auto;
     -webkit-flex: auto;
         -ms-flex: auto;
             flex: auto;    
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:   flex-end;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="s_container seleccion_simple_default">                          
    <div class="ssm_opcion">
        <p>Prueba</p>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your html as well so we can see the structure

Comment: The classes are fine, I've just modified before paste it here. I've solved the problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
-webkit-box-pack: end;
-webkit-box-align: center;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!

Comment: I need to align text within the div with the properties flex offer, but wasn't working in the Android browser as it uses an old syntax. This is the fix:
-webkit-box-pack: end;
-webkit-box-align: center;